# Combine the data in both sets from within the notebook into a single dataframe by joining them based on the common zipcodes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe and There is following question:

Capture the data sets from the two sites: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-registered-foreclosure-properties and https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2010-census-populations-by-zip-code which contain data on property foreclosures and demographic data in the City of Los Angeles, respectively, from within the notebook.

Combine the data in both sets from within the notebook into a single dataframe by joining them based on the common zipcodes. To complete this task, you must first count the number of foreclosures of each type (single family, multi-family, ..) in each zip code. The end result of this step would be a single data frame with the columns shown below. Display the first 10 lines of this combined data frame.
Zip code - Total Males - Total Females - Total Households - Average Household size - total number of single family foreclosures - total number of multi-family foreclosures

I need for answer, please

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have a bit more luck if you provide additional information. What have you tried so far? What's not working? What specifically are you having difficulty with in the above problem? As stated it seems like you have some sort of a homework problem you want solved for you, which I doubt will get you much help.

Comment: There are two files 
First one:  https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-registered-foreclosure-properties
Second one: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2010-census-populations-by-zip-code

Both i had read them using data frame, with make Zip code columns for each file equal to each other, and find count for some columns and not list all columns (list some of them)